# How to open a new browser in R when an actionbutton is clicked?

Tags: r, shiny

How to open a new browser in R when an actionbutton is clicked?And this new browser should display a form created and defined inside fluidpage:

For example

```
observeEvent (input$button1, {
  output$view <- renderUI({isolate({
      div(id="view1",
     fluidPage(shinyjs::useShinyjs(),
         fluidRow(column(3,
         textInput("mrdno",label = "MRD NO:",value="111")),
    column(3,
    textInput("namevpmodify",label = "NAME",value="AAA") )
     )))
})})})
```

I want to display the form defined inside `div id="view1"` to be displayed in another browser window when the button button 1 is clicked.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can create a separate window without a second instance of R (i.e. a second Shiny app). You can easily open a new window with arbitrary HTML, but it won't be linked to R in the server like the Shiny app, so you won't be able to include a `textInput`, but there may be a way to get the new window to talk to the server (I doubt it though). See example below for creating new window with arbitrary HTML:

```
library(shiny)
runApp(
  list(
    ui = fluidPage(
      tags$script(
        "Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('new-page', function(HTML) { 
          var w=window.open();
          $(w.document.body).html(HTML);
        });"  
      ),
      textInput("html","Enter arbitrary HTML"),
      actionButton("btn","Press Me to render HTML in new window")
    ),
    server = function(input, output, session) {
      observeEvent(input$btn,{
        session$sendCustomMessage("new-page",list(
          HTML(
              input$html
            )
          )
        )
      })
    }
  )
)
```

You may be interested in the `shinyBS` package's ability to create modal windows. So you would want something in the UI like

```
bsModal("view1","pickAname","button1",  fluidRow(column(3,
         textInput("mrdno",label = "MRD NO:",value="111")),
    column(3,
    textInput("namevpmodify",label = "NAME",value="AAA") )
```

Comment: Thank you Sir,but I am creating the button button1 at the server side in another button's observeevent,then how should the code be written as the bsModel is written inside the ui.R and the id button1 is not available there.